# Exception when trying to use PageFactory in selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate simple web application, for that, I am using Page Object Model Pattern, with Selenium and Java,
My maven pom dependencies look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.13.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My Page Object Class looks like this:

```
public class Page {
    public Page(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    @FindBy(linkText = "Players")
    private WebElement playersLink;

    public boolean isPlayersLinkVisible(){
        return playersLink.isDisplayed();
    }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
public class Test{
  @Test
  public void test(){
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(URL);
        Page page = new Page(driver);
        System.out.println(page.isPlayersLinkVisible());
  }
}
```

But I am getting this exception, and can't figure out why?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WrapsElement

at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.proxyForLocator(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:79)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because the selenium support version was different than the other selenium libraries I was using. The issue is fixed when the same version is used for all selenium libraries including the selenium support library in pom.xml

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had the same issue and resolved by upgrading old libraries in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out, apparently there were incompatible dependencies, I removed unnecessary ones and left only the ones I need:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.13.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```